# Stop URL tag redirection to my homepage

Tags: htaccess, redirects, tags

I'm trying to find a way to stop tag redirections to the homepage so that 
`https://example.com/?something` stops redirecting to `https://example.com`.

Similarly, any URL which is followed by a question mark (`?`) I want to be redirected to the 404 page instead of the site homepage.

Comment: "`https://example.com/?something` stops redirecting to `https://example.com`" - Are you actually seeing an _external redirect_, as you state? In which case you need to find the source of that redirect. Or is the homepage simply served at the URL `https://example.com/?something` - no redirection - which would be expected/default behaviour?

Comment: And what do you want to happen when receiving a request for `https://example.com/?something`? A 404, as mentioned in the 2nd part of the question?

Comment: Hello :)
The homepage is served without any issues. I want to stop the ?something to be redirected to the homepage. This is a default action probably from the server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> any URL which is followed by a question mark (`?`) I want to be redirected to the 404 page

Using mod_rewrite at the top of your `.htaccess` file you can do something like the following to serve a 404 for any request that contains a query string (the part after the first `?`).

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]
```

The single dot in the *CondPattern* (2nd argument to the `RewriteCond` directive) matches any character in the query string. If no match, ie. no query string, then the 404 is not served.

Note that this is not an external "redirect". The 404 error document is served via an internal subrequest.

> `https://example.com/?something` stops redirecting to `https://example.com`

I'm assuming there is no actual "redirect" here and the home page is simply being served at that URL. `https://example.com/?something` is, after all, the URL for the home page (an empty URL-path), just with an additional query string.

However, if you are seeing an external redirect to `https://example.com/`, then this is something you need to resolve first - where is the "redirect" coming from?

---

> **UPDATE:** This is about a hacked site where Google has chaced for months pages with spam content.

To get these "spam" URLs removed as quick as possible from Google then consider sending a "410 Gone" instead of a standard 404. A 410 is a stronger signal for Google that the page is never coming back and should drop the result quicker.

To do this, simply change the `R=404` to `G` (short for `R=410`) in the above `RewriteRule` directive. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^ - [G]
```

To serve a 410 Gone for any request that contains a query string (everything after the first `?`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. This is about a hacked site where Google has chaced for months pages with spam content.

Those pages URLs are similar to https://example.com?q=hfgf or https://example.com/?hydftgd

Even though the hack has been removed Google still has those spam pages cached because on their part they don't serve a 404 since they redirect to the homepage as 301 or 302.

Comment: If these URLs are the result of a hack and to get them removed from Google as-soon-as then consider sending a 410 instead of a 404. I've updated my answer.